# How can i change the Font?

Tags: fonts, font-face

I have the following problem.
If I use Ghostscript to create a PDF from my old dos system, the font NIMBUSMONO is automatically used

can someone explain to me where and how I can change the output font to arial for example under Ghostscript?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for your Feedback.   I am not familiar with Ghostscript at all. it was more about a change of font in general.

Can you Tell me what files do you need to propose a change?

Comment: OK, If i create the PDF-File via Ghostscript. The PDF Shows me as the Creator the following: GPL Ghostscript 9.20 (ps2write). In which File do i have to Change the Font? So far i have not Set anything in Ghostscript. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but i dont instand anything Here...where should i do what and how? My Situation i have an old DOS Software. The Print File is created by Programm called printfil. This creates a PDF with the Help of Ghostscript. (PCL-driver). Since i dont have to do anything Here and the PDF is created for me immediately. I dont know how to Run Ghostscript Independently and how to use the commands....  I Just want to Change the Font of NimbusMono to another Font of Windows. This must be possible with a simple Change in a File or Not?? I Just need the steps i have to Talk after one... Thanks

Comment: Ok my situation is: I using an old DOS-System with DOSBox. In the background i opened the software printfil. This enables lpt1,lpt2... to be redirected to new printers. If I then print, a pcl-driver is generated via printfil and gs. The file is created directly. Problem : No matter what font I set in my dos-system -driver, Ghostscript always uses the same font NimbusMono...    
Printfil fetches GS for help via the following directories : GS Path      : C:\gs\bin\GsWin32c.exe|.T. - C:\WINDOWS\system32\Spool\Drivers\Color\sRGB Color Space Profile.icm - C:\ghostpcl-9.20-win32\gpcl6win32.exe.

Comment: Yes, there is an option, but I use the PCL mode and not the GDI mode.. I need the PCL-Mode...   I still think that ghostscript is the problem, the NimbusMono will be embedded as a standard font, this has to be changed... but how?

Comment: i can't upload a file, the given link is wrong